# Adding custom labels to jvm related metrics using jmx_exporter

Tags: apache-kafka, jmx, metrics, prometheus

I want to add custom labels `"key:my-app"` for the `jvm.*` or `process.*` related metrics when using [prometheus_jmx_exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter) with kafka. I couldn't figure out the rules/patterns to be used for the same. Logged Github comment as well on a similar [issue](https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter/issues/111), but no response.

The following doesn't add the label `"services="my-app"` to the generated metrics:

```
rules:
- pattern : process.cpu.seconds.total
  name: kafka_process_cpu_seconds_total
  labels:
    services: "my-app"
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Prometheus such labels are called target labels, and are applied to on the Prometheus end. Usually this is done with `relabel_configs`, based on metadata from service discovery.

Comment: Will check. Thanks. Can you plz advice if the .yml config I pasted above can be modified in any way to get the desired labels in in JMX O/P?